# pandas datetime conversions adding .0 to column values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have an excel file that infers the datetime column correctly with the time, which I don't need. What I do need is to create a month, quarter, year, and year_quarter column derived from the datetime column. But, instead of getting the results I've successfully gotten in prior iterations I'm getting an odd '.0' within the values in each column.

I've done this without any trouble in the past based on a simple function like the one down below:

```
def add_date_periods(df):
    #df['ddate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ddate'])
    df['ddate'] = df['ddate'].dt.date
    df['dyear'] = (df['ddate'].dt.year).apply(str)
    df['dqtr'] = (df['ddate'].dt.quarter).apply(str)
    df['dmonth'] = (df['ddate'].dt.month).apply(str)
    df['yrqtr'] = df['dyear'].apply(str) + 'Q' + df['dqtr'].apply(str)
```

Expected object dtype values for each column {'dyear':'2018', 'dqtr':'3','dmonth':'9','yrqtr':'2018Q3'}

Actual object dtype values returned {'dyear':'2018', 'dqtr':'3.0','dmonth':'9.0','yrqtr':'2018.0Q3.0'}

I thought a .replace('.0', '') could solve my problem but that shortened the year to the last two digits ('18', '18Q3'), which I then tried to append in front of the year and year quarter columns but encountered another issue where a large chunk of month values to converted to 0. I'm at a loss and can simply not figure out why these issues persist even after changing the order of operations (str to dt and vice versa) multiple times.

Comment: Most likely your data frame contains invalid/nan data. I tried on ` pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(['2018-09-01', '2019-01-01']))` and it works fine. Also, do not use `apply(str)`, try `astype(str)`.

Comment: I can't say for sure I've encountered null dates (NaT) while doing this operation before. I know they are notorious for misbehavior in pandas calculations but thought they would just transfer over to the other derived columns. In this case I filled them with appropriate dates instead of dropping and it did the trick, so thank you! Still would love to know why so few (11/140,000)  nulls caused 11,500 months to be empty strings and if that had anything to do with the .0 which were in all 140k rows.

Comment: because (i've recently learned that) `nan` is treated as `float`. So if your series has nan values, the entire series will be treated as float, even when you `apply`.

Comment: Duly noted, those floats did not guide my attention towards the nulls for debugging.

Comment: Make the column `'Int64'` type.